# EasyAdmin 3 - How to add non-entity fields && how to autofill siblings fields dinamically

Tags: symfony5, easyadmin

I am a newbie using EasyAdmin 3.x and I am having trouble trying to achieve the task below.

I have the entity User with fields:
...

- sapContactId (string field)
- email
  ...

Well, I've been asked to add to the creating form 4 non-entity fields: name, surname, position and department (the fields could be added to the entity, if needed). Also, I need to put a button to be clicked and autofill the four fields mentioned above. I guess I need to call a controller and there, get the data from the webservice and inject it to the form.

How can I achieve this? I've read the documentation and I still have no idea how to get this done. Any advice? Should I use instead a custom entity type form in a custom action controller? And how? Also, I don't know how I could autofill another fields neither... using form events?

Any help is very welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well for autofill  entity properties you could use subscribers in symfony 5
an set BeforeEntityPresistEvent function and fill your missing properties
You should follow this documentation https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/events.html